# need to display the distinct values in my report comming from xml using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I want to display the distinct values of PRODUCT DETAIL which are getting from xml
for every ORDER we have PRODUCT DETAIL in database ,some orders may have same PRODUCT DETAIL This we will display on invoice report.
we usually  use this to get data

<query name="ORDER_DETAIL" value="SELECT ORDER_DETAIL.PRODUCT_DETAIL DETAIL, ORDER_DETAIL.PRODUCT_NAME NAME, FROM ORDER_DETAIL ORDER_DETAIL INNER JOIN PRODUCT_DETAIL DETAIL ON PRODUCT_DETAIL.ID = ORDER__DETAIL.ID WHERE ORDER_DETAIL.ID=? "

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http:www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >

<fo:table-cell padding=".5mm">
<fo:block font-size="10pt"> PRODUCT DETAIL
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="//invoice_h/invoice_d/order_detail/@product_detail != '' ">
<xsl:for-each select="//invoice_h/invoice_d/order_detail/@product_detail">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

when I try this on XSLT 1.0 I can get the PRODUCT DETAIL which shows duplicates as like
`PRODUCT DETAIL : SHOES,SHOES,SHOES,SHOES,TRUOSER,SHIRT`

on my report

tried with `distinct-values()` but it thrown exception

I even tried to apply

```
generate-id()
```

on my xslt

````
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="//invoice_h/invoice_d/order_detail/@product_detail != '' ">
<xsl:for-each select="//invoice_h/invoice_d/order_detail/@product_detail">
<xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(//invoice_h/invoice_d/order_detail/@product_detail[. = current()][1])" >
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<br />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>```

but I can get only first value on my report 

`PRODUCT DETAIL : SHOES`

I need to display only distinct values on my report even though few ORDER's have same PRODUCT DETAIL

like ORDER#1   SHOES
     ORDER#2   SHOES
     ORDER#3   SHOES
     ORDER#4   TROUSER
     ORDER#5   SHIRT

expected output ::

`PRODUCT DETAIL : SHOES , TROUSER , SHIRT`
````

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing example input and the expected output. Note that some XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension  function.

Comment: I have no prior knowledge on this michael.! so that I am not able to show perfect example .since it is on part of my project ..! but, I hope all my example and expected is mentioned over there..!

Comment: What do you mean by "I have no prior knowledge on this"? If you don't know what your input looks like, how do you expect to process it?

Comment: we have a lot of sql queries for every thing to display presently product detail is getting from this query

Comment: 1. Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and put the code there. 2. The input to XSLT is XML, not SQL. If you cannot see the input directly, then use an XSLT with only the identity transform template to get at it.

Comment: ok michael.! can you help me how to get the required thing. I know I didnt produced minimal code but,I tried all my possibilities.

Comment: No I can't and no you didn't.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I can produce only this information thats all I had. Im trying this from 2 days I cant get it.

Comment: could you suggest any possibilities ..! will you please